# Calculation of resultant pH

Tags: ph, concentration

> A solution with $\mathrm{pH}=4$ is mixed with a solution with $\mathrm{pH}=10$ in equal volumes. Calculate resultant $\mathrm{pH}$.
>   Please note both solution consists of strong acids and/or bases i.e. They will completely dissociate.

$Method 1:$

Let volume be 1L of each

pH of solution 1=4

Concentration of H is $10^{-4} $

pH of solution 2=10

Concentration of H is $10^{-10} $

Resultant concentration =$\frac{10^{-4} +10^{-10} }{2}$

Therefore calculting pH we get 4.301

$Method 2:$

pH of solution 1=4

Concentration of H is $10^{-4} $

pH of solution 2=10

pOH=14-10=4

Concentration of OH=$10^{-4} $

Hence the H and OH neutralizes each other so it will result in neutral solution ph=7

Edit:
I found another method which is kind of same as method 2

Method 3

In Solution 1:
pH=4. Concentration of H is $10^{-4} $

Since pOH=14-pH. Hence pOH=10. Therefore concentration of OH=$10^{-10} $

In solution 2

pH=10. Concentration of H is $10^{-10} $

Since pOH=14-pH. Hence pOH=4. Therefore concentration of OH=$10^{-4} $

So the total concentration of H=concentration of OH

Hence neutrilization reaction would occur and resultant pH will be 7

Which method is right and why??

Comment: The second method, so to put it, is slightly _less wrong_. But in fact we can't calculate the resulting pH at all. We don't have the necessary data. Knowing the pH of original solutions is simply not enough.

Comment: Can you please explain why is it so??

Comment: What else is required??

Comment: We need to know what compounds are there.

Comment: Why do we need that?? I couldn't get your point. I think if it is given that solution2 has pH 10 it will be basic and that means we have a basic compound and the other will be acidic as its pH is 4

Comment: A dilute solution of a strong acid and a concentrated solution of a weak acid might have identical pH, but very different neutralization behavior.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me Both the compound are strong acids and base

Comment: Then the second method will do.

Comment: And is the third method i mentioned in edit correct??

Comment: How is it different from method 2?

Comment: Method 1 would work for a 'normal solution' but in the acid/base case there is the equilibrium $\ce{H^+ + OH^- <=>H2O}$ and so recognising is what you do in method 2.

Comment: The specification that strong acids and bases are used is enough to calculate that the final pH is 7. No further decimals are used in the description of the problem, so the fact that the final pH may be 0.01 or 0.02 off is not significant. The concentrations of H+ and OH- are equal; the volumes are equal; the strengths are equal. Nothing more is needed.